# Matrix Creation from Sum of Entries of Another Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I am trying to use a matrix to approximate another.

I have a 1000x96 matrix called *Bpp* and I need to create a new matrix, *Omega*, from it, in this form:

[image: Approx of Matrix]

where b′′(z_i)_l is the i,l entry of Bpp (Bpp is a 1000x96 matrix)

I have this attempt:

```
Omega = matrix(0, 96, 96)

for(k in 1:96){
   for(l in 1:96){
     Omega[k,l] = sum(Bpp[,k]*Bpp[,l]*delta)
   }
}
```

But I'm almost certain it isn't right, as it's not producing the results I need in a later problem.

Thanks in advance for help/guidance.

Comment: In the link above, what do those values stand for ? Better, if you can explain the equation in simple english. Without knowing exactly, hard to form a solution. Surely, you don't need loops for this, you can do matrix multiplication, much faster option.

Comment: @YOLO n the link, each b is the i,k/l entry of the Bpp matrix with the above dimensions. So for example, b''(z_2)_3 would be the entry in the second row and third column of Bpp.  Does that clarify it?

Comment: okay, and what is the value for delta ?

Comment: it's a constant, in this case, it ends up being 0.01616617

Comment: *It's not producing the results*... not producing *any* results or incorrect results? Please set up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a smaller matrix *Bpp* maybe `4x4` and then show desired *Omega*. `dput(Bpp[4,4])` is one way. To be clear, show us input data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do the inner product. It will multiply and sum each column of `Bpp` and all its 96 columns, the same thing your loop does.

```
Omega = t(Bpp)*Bpp*delta
```